# How do I solve this second order partial derivative?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

The answer I got was by first finding the partial derivative with respect to r which I found to be 2r/(r^2 + s) and then I squared it and got 4r^2/(r^2 + s)^2 
I plugged this into wolfram alpha and it gave a different answer, can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Original Question (Number 2)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The second order derivative does not mean "take the derivative and square the result".  The notation actually means "take the derivative,  and then take the derivative of your result".